# I need to calculate a global average in a netCDF CF file using weighted latitudes using xarray then convert to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I need to calculate a global time series (time) from a netCDF cf data 3D (time,lat,lon) file then convert it to a pandas/dataframe. I need to weight the latitude by cos(lat). I have been using numpy to do the averages but the conversion to a pandas/dataframe to the weighted array doesn't work.

```
ds=xr.open_dataset('sample_data.nc')
data=ds.tas
start_time='1980-01-01'
end_time='2018-12-31'
time_slice = slice(start_time, end_time)
nrows=len(data.lat.values)
ncols=len(data.lon.values)
t=len(data.time.values)
weights=np.zeros([len(data.lat.values)])
latsr = np.deg2rad(data.lat.values).reshape((nrows,1))
weight_matrix=np.repeat(np.cos(latsr),ncols,axis=1)
wghtpr=np.zeros_like(data)
for i in range (0,t):
    wghtpr[i,:,:]=data[i,:,:]*weight_matrix
new_data=wghtpr
wtdata=np.average(new_data,axis=1)
da=np.average(wtdata,axis=1)
```

This ends up with a nuumpy array with no "name"

If I do a ds, I get:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (bnds: 2, lat: 361, lon: 576, time: 477)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1980-01-16T12:00:00 ... 2019-09-16
  * lat        (lat) float64 -90.0 -89.5 -89.0 -88.5 ... 88.5 89.0 89.5 90.0
  * lon        (lon) float64 0.0 0.625 1.25 1.875 ... 357.5 358.1 358.8 359.4
    height     float64 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds
Data variables:
    time_bnds  (time, bnds) datetime64[ns] ...
    lat_bnds   (lat, bnds) float64 ...
    lon_bnds   (lon, bnds) float64 ...
    tas        (time, lat, lon) float32 244.15399 244.15399 ... 267.52875
Attributes:
    institution:     Global Modeling and Assimilation Office, NASA Goddard Sp...
    institute_id:    NASA-GMAO
    experiment_id:   MERRA-2
    source:          MERRA-2 Monthly tavgM_2d_slv_Nx
    model_id:        GEOS-5
    references:      http://gmao.gsfc.nasa.gov/research/merra/, http://gmao.g...
    tracking_id:     e77fd4de-19c2-45ad-afe2-ce3f6c1eb148
    mip_specs:       CMIP5
    source_id:       MERRA-2
    product:         reanalysis
    frequency:       mon
    creation_date:   2015-10-11T23:12:34Z
    history:         2015-10-11T23:12:34Z CMOR rewrote data to comply with CF...
    Conventions:     CF-1.4
    project_id:      CREATE-IP
    table_id:        Table Amon_ana (10 March 2011) c3ffdce87438d8df0839620ee...
    title:           Reanalysis output prepared for CREATE-IP.
    modeling_realm:  atmos
    cmor_version:    2.9.1
    doi:             http://dx.doi.org/10.5067/AP1B0BA5PD2K
    contact:         MERRA-2, Steven Pawson (steven.pawson-1@nasa.gov)
#
```

Comment: could you please include a print out of what you get when you just type `ds`? It'd be helpful to see the metadata, and also what other variables are in the dataset (sometimes there's something helpful hidden in there!)

Comment: And building on @AWilliams3142 's comment, if you can produce a reproducible example, that makes it much easier for others to engage. From the description, this should be a very easy operation in xarray.

Comment: I added the output from ds.

Comment: I'll try to get a small sample of the data to reproduce the error but any 2D array of CF compliant netCDF files (e.g. CMIP5) with one variable per file should work as input.

Answer (score 0):

To make use of `xarray`'s broadcasting and alignment, you may do the weighting like this:

```py
ds=xr.open_dataset('sample_data.nc')
data=ds.tas

#start_time='1980-01-01'
#end_time='2018-12-31'
#time_slice = slice(start_time, end_time)
#nrows=len(data.lat.values)
#ncols=len(data.lon.values)
#t=len(data.time.values)

latsr = xr.ufunc.deg2rad(data.lat)
weights = xr.ufunc.cos(latsr)
weighted = data * weights # broadcasting here
weighted_mean = weighted.mean(['lat','lon'])

# to pandas
df = weighted_mean.to_dataframe()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use CDO. To get the global mean you should only need to do the following:

```
cdo fldmean 'sample_data.nc' out.nc
```

If on Linux, you can also use my Python package nctoolkit which uses CDO as a backend (https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html). Calculating the global mean and then converting it to pandas would require the following:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
data = nc.open_data("sample_data.nc")
data.spatial_mean()
pd_ts = data.to_dataframe()
```

Plotting the time series would require:

```
data.plot()
```